# Can you send mapping information when you post an index to Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch

```
url ="https://elasticurl/new_index/_doc"
let obj = {
    "@timestamp": now.toISOString(),
    "level": "INFO",
    "type": report_type,
    "data": {
        "sample_key": sample_value,
        "sample_key": sample_value,
        "sample_key": sample_value,
        "sample_key": sample_value,
        "sample_key": sample_value,
        "sample_key": sample_value,
        "sample_key": sample_value,
        "sample_key": sample_value,
        "sample_key": sample_value,
        "sample_key": sample_value,
        "sample_key": sample_value 
    }
};


axios.post(url, obj, {
        auth: {
            username: uname,
            password: pass
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(`Update Elasticsearch ${objstr}`);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(`Fail to update Elasticsearch ${error.response.status}: ${error.response.statusText}`);
    });
```

So, here is the scenario:

- we are creating a new index (done using axios post)
- we are sending an object as data to this new index
- this creates a mapping like so:

```
{ "uuid123-log-2021.05.31": { "mappings": { "properties": { "@timestamp": { "type": "date" }, "data": { "properties": { "sample_key": { "type": "text", "fields": { "keyword": { "type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 } } }, "sample_key": { "type": "text", "fields": { "keyword": { "type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 } } }, "sample_key": { "type": "text", "fields": { "keyword": { "type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 } } }
```

since the data type is "text", "fielddata" is set to false by default

this will prevent us from running query on this newly created index

How do we send mapping info which creates data type "keyword" when creating new index. So that we can run query on this new index

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the framework you are using but you essentially need to create custom mapping and not rely on dynamic mapping.

See ES-Doc [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/explicit-mapping.html)

Comment: Thank you for replying.
* there is no framework being used
* the document you linked has this

```PUT /my-index-000001
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "age":    { "type": "integer" },  
      "email":  { "type": "keyword"  }, 
      "name":   { "type": "text"  }     
    }
  }
}```

This as far as I know is a PUT request which updates the index's mappings. I want to create mappings when I create a new index, is it possible?